# Auto launch a program on login for Raspbian or Debian

Tags: bash, shell, debian, shell-script, raspbian

I am making a application on the Raspberry Pi, and I want it so if you login to the Pi directly, or through SSH, it will launch this application.

This application is made to only work in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up programs to run from login through that users `.profile` or `.bashrc`. I would recommend using `.profile` so it works with all shells.

If you have many users, instead of editing each `.profile`, you could create a default profile at `/etc/profile` and remove the current `.profile` from their directories.

Add the entry like this: `. mycommand`